# How can I tell that a query runs multi-threaded in QuestDB?

Tags: questdb

I'm running the following query in QuestDB:

```sql
SELECT 
    timestamp,
    first(price) AS open,
    last(price) AS close,
    min(price),
    max(price),
    sum(amount) AS volume
FROM trades
WHERE symbol = 'BTC-USD' AND timestamp > dateadd('d', -1, now())
SAMPLE BY 15m ALIGN TO CALENDAR;
```

How can I tell that this query uses all available cores on the server?

Comment: I removed the general, ISO SQL tag, since this is very questdb specific.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the execution plan for your query. You can see it by adding EXPLAIN clause at the beginning of the query text:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    timestamp,
    first(price) AS open,
    last(price) AS close,
    min(price),
    max(price),
    sum(amount) AS volume
FROM trades
WHERE symbol = 'BTC-USD' AND timestamp > dateadd('d', -1, now())
SAMPLE BY 15m ALIGN TO CALENDAR;
```

If you see `Async ...` nodes in the output, e.g. `Async JIT Group By` or `Async JIT Filter`, it means that the corresponding parts of the query execution plan run in parallel, i.e. on multiple threads.

Note that by default, parallel execution is disabled on machines with less than 4 cores.

Also, in many cases, if your query runs on a single thread, you can rewrite it in a parallel-friendly way. Sometimes this can be as simple as moving the aggregates and the filter from the outer query for the sub-query.

Here is a simple example:

```sql
SELECT symbol, sum(price)
FROM (
    SELECT symbol, price FROM trades
    UNION ALL
    SELECT symbol, price FROM trades
)
WHERE symbol = 'BTC-USD';
```

This query will run single-threaded since the GROUP BY and the filter is applied to a UNION ALL sub-query. But if you rewrite it in the following way, both parts of the sub-query will be handled on multiple threads:

```sql
SELECT symbol, sum(price)
FROM (
    SELECT symbol, sum(price) FROM trades
    WHERE symbol = 'BTC-USD'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT symbol, sum(price) FROM trades
    WHERE symbol = 'BTC-USD'
);
```

Comment: So what will you do in case the query does not use all cores, but you want it to do so? I think you should add this information to your answer.

Comment: Good idea, will add that.